# Select com 3 condiçoes e uma delas dependente de uma quarta condição

Tags: sql

Estou populando um gráfico e para isso preciso selecionar os dados de cada usuário no banco, tabela `financeiro`. Todavia não quero mostrar registros do campo `label_chart` que estejam vazios, nem campos `qdade_stream` com valor zero, exceto se o campo `label_chart = inicio` (nesse caso o campo `qdade_stream` pode ter valor zero).

```
SELECT * FROM financeiro WHERE id_usuario = 150 AND label_chart !='' AND (qdade_stream != 0 AND label_chart <>'inicio')
ORDER BY order_chart";
```

Da maneira que estou fazendo, a query não retorna a linha cujo `label_chart=inicio`, porque como o seu valor é igual a zero, a query só obedece à condição de apenas retornar `qdade_stream != 0`

Answer (score -1):

A lógica da sua query está quase certa, só se confundiu um pouco nos operadores que vai usar. Como tem duas condições que fazer ser possível exibir resultado o ideal vai ser usar o `OR`, então ficaria:

```
SELECT * 
FROM financeiro 
WHERE id_usuario = 150 
  AND ((label_chart != '' AND qdade_stream != 0) OR label_chart = 'inicio')
ORDER BY order_chart;
```

Dessa forma ele pega os registros com `id_registro = 150` e com `label_chart` e `qdade_strem` diferentes de vazio ou zero OU apenas com `label_chart` igual à inicio sem levar em conta a `qdade_stream`.

Comment: Testei esse código, mas parece haver algum erro, pois nao retornou nada, o gráfico nem sequer se formou.

Comment: Não sei qual implementação do SQL você ta usando (MySQL, SQL server, ...) então não sei se pode ser problema usar o `!=` ao invés do `<>`, talvez valha a pena testar isso. Se não for isso fica dificil saber o que pode estar ocorrendo sem saber como estão seus dados.

Comment: Estou usando MySQL. Tenho 4 gráficos, só essa query que não consigo retornar o que eu preciso, como explicado no meu enunciado. Também não consigo saber o que está ocorrendo. E não entendi o que você precisa saber sobre os dados do banco, pois é uma tabela normal.